# $a^{n-1}=1\pmod n$ but $a^d\neq 1 \pmod n$ for every proper divisor $d$ of $n-1$. Prove that $n$ is a prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $a$ and $n>1$ be any integers such that $a^{n-1}=1\pmod n$ but $a^d\neq 1 \pmod n$ for every proper divisor $d$ of $n-1$. Prove that $n$ is a prime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $n$ is composite. Then $\def\Z{\Bbb Z}\Z/n\Z$ has zero divisors, so its group of invertible elements has less than $n-1$ elements. In particular, it cannot contain an element of order$~n-1$, like $a$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some hints:

— What is the order of $[a]_n$ in $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^{\times}$ ? Recall that in any group $G$, $g^k=1$ iff the order of $g$ divides $k$.

— The order of $[a]_n$ divides the order of $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^{\times}$, which is $\phi(n)$.

— An integer $n$ is prime iff $\phi(n)≥n-1$ (where $\phi(n)$ is the number of integers $k$ between $1$ and $n$ that are coprime with $n$).